# Submit jquery form based on return values from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I want to display in `#username_input` according to the value that that php script returns. It seems that the if condition is not working.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#username_input').keyup(function () {
            $.post('header/check_username.php', {
                    username: form.username.value
                },
                function (result_username) {
                    if (result_username == 'a') {

                        $('#feedback_username').html('choose a username').show();
                    }
                    if (result_username == 'b') {
                        $('#feedback_username').html('Too short').show();
                    }

                });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<form id="registeration_form" name="form" onsubmit="return hello()" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username_input" name="username" autofucus/></td>
            <td><span id="feedback_username"></span></td>
            <br/><br/>
        <tr>
            <td>Password </td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password_input" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <br/><br/>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm"/></td>
            <td><span id="feedback_password"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <br/><br/>
        <tr>
            <td>Email </td>
            <td><input type="text" id= "email_input" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <center><input type="submit" x value="Register"/></center>
    <br/>
    <div id= "onsubmit_feedback"></div>
    <center><a href="javascript:register('hide');">close</a></center>
</form>
```

It returns `a` if username is empty and `b` if username is less than 6 characters.

PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "", "project_new");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

    echo "Unsuccessful" . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

@$username      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['username']));
$check          = mysqli_query($con, "select u from users where u ='$username'");
$check_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($username == NULL)
    retutn 'a';
    //echo "choose a username";
else if (strlen($username) <= 5)
    return 'b';
    //echo "Too Short. Minimum 6 characters";
else {
    if ($check_num_rows == 0)
        echo "Available :)";
    else if ($check_num_rows == 1)
        echo "Not Available :( ";

}

?>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Send the username to the server with ajax, and if it's too short, pop up an error message, and if it's long enough, submit a form with the username and redirect. Must be an easier way to do that ?

Comment: This >>> `retutn 'a';`, typo? Has to read as `return 'a';`. If it's not a typo then change it, try it again, then get back with your results.

Comment: use `echo` instead of `return`, (ie: `echo 'a';`)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I've found (one already mentioned by @Fred in comments) in the following two lines:

```
if ($username==NULL)
    retutn 'a';
```

First, your `$username` will never be null.  `mysqli_real_escape_string` returns string.  Second line `retutn 'a'` is probably a typo as suggested by Fred.

Try changing these lines to:

```
if (empty($username))
    echo 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies within the wrong callback function and the PHP string. After API documentation of jQuery the callback function on success gets three parameters (data, textStatus, jqXHR).

Try this solution for the PHP file:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "", "project_new");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

    echo "Unsuccessful" . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$username      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['username']));
$check          = mysqli_query($con, "select u from users where u ='$username'");
$check_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if (empty($username)) {
    echo 'a';
    //echo "choose a username";
}
else if (strlen($username) <= 5) {
    return 'b';
    //echo "Too Short. Minimum 6 characters";
}
else {
    if ($check_num_rows == 0)
        echo "Available :)";
    else if ($check_num_rows == 1)
        echo "Not Available :( ";

}

?>
```

And this for the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username_input').keyup(function () {
        $.post('header/check_username.php', {
                username: form.username.value
            },
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data == 'a') {

                    $('#feedback_username').html('choose a username').show();
                }
                if (data == 'b') {
                    $('#feedback_username').html('Too short').show();
                }

            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably want to make a hidden div with choose username and a div for Too Short. If you wanne translate it later to another language, it can be done faster :)